# I want to use jdk8 on vscode recent extension, how to set on setting.json

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-8

hello I use vs code to develop java.
I want to use jdk8 but vs code extension highly recommend
jdk11 or recent.
Please let me know how to set setting.json for using jdk8.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notification is just asking you to install JDK11 to run vscode-java extension itself.

If you want to run your program at JDK8, you can install both JDK 8 and JDK 11 in your machine, and configure them in the user settings below:

```
"java.home": "<the path to jdk11>",
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "default": true,
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "<the path to jdk8>",
    }
]
```

You can also achieve this function by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open Command Platte and choose **Java: Configure Java Runtime**.

[image]

You can choose JDK1.8 for **Project JDKs**;

Choose JDK11 or rencent version as **Java Tooling Time**.

Comment: @SukChan Yoon, If my answer helps you, it's appreciated that you can mark it.